# jquery ui default dialog close icon

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, icons

I'm embarrassed to post a question on here which would seem so trivial, but I've already smashed my allotted keyboards for the month.

Yesterday I updated my jquery from 1.4.4 -> 1.9, ui-1.10 (wow, right?). This came with its own set of problems and code revisions - major ones in place and working as expected, except...

[image]

The stupid default dialog 'x' icon which is not centered on its cell, but 'floating' slightly to the right and below. I've inspected the surrounding elements and adjusted every applicable css class to try to nudge it back into place with no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/libs/jquery/css/jquery-css-1.10.3.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
```

Thoughts?

This delight is for your time and trouble:

[image]

Comment: you updated the jquery UI css also right?

Comment: Yessir I did. 1.10.3 - Updated code segment

Comment: in that case it looks like some of your local styles might be interfering with the UI style... can you inspect the close button and see what are the css rules applied... and see whether any other css rules apart from the once from jquery-ui.css is getting applied

Comment: @Arun: One of my thoughts as well. I removed all additional styling and still no avail. Would you say this is a certainty, I missed something somewhere ?

Comment: I can say that 99% that could be the case... but without seeing the actual page can't say 100%... also which is the theme used

Comment: I suppose the best way to prove your theory is to recreate the dialog in a control. I'll reply with results.

Comment: try it in a independent page and test it

Comment: Arun nailed it. Hidden style tucked away deep. Sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: good..... have a nice day then